# Unique sorted list of column values from 2 tables

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I need to get a list of unique email addresses across 2 table. For example I have the selects:

```
select distinct
     email
from
     contacts
order by
     email

select distinct
     email
from
     customers
order by
     email
```

If I only needed one of those, piece of cake. If I wanted them as 2 columns side by side, also piece of cake.

But how do I get them as a single column, no duplicates, sorted? This will be running on Azure Sql Database if that is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like:

```
select distinct email from contacts order by email // Your first query
union
select distinct email from customers order by email // Your second query
```

The `union` creates a single column email with data from both queries and already eliminates duplicates, unlike `union all`.

For the ordering, just add `ORDER BY email` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct 
     email 
from (
     select distinct email from contacts order by email 
     union all 
     select distinct email from customers order by email
     ) as emails
```